# Repeate an angular2 component on an asp.net5 view

Tags: asp.net-core, angular

I create a rating component and try to use it in an asp.net 5 view inside a `foreach` like this code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.Items)
            {
                <my-rating> </my-rating>
            }
```

my issue is that the component only instantiated one time for first item of the list.

Thank to any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should have a look at the corresponding code in your browser. I mean: do you have several `<my-rating></my-rating>` in your browser using for example the Element tab of Chrome dev tools.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: My component render only one time on the page. -Thank to involve in my  problem :)

Comment: You're welcome! Do you mean that's the expected behavior or you want to have several component (one per element in the list)? Could you give us you complete view? Thanks!

Comment: The expected behavior is my component render for each item in `@foreach`. So I want to have several component (one per element in the list.

Comment: Do you have this: `<!-- Elt1 --><my-rating></my-rating><!-- Elt2 --><my-rating></my-rating> ...` or only `<my-rating></my-rating>` in the HTML content you receive from your asp.net 5 (server-side) application?

Answer (score 0):

You can only boostrap one app per page in angular2.

Comment: Can you explain more a bit. I bootstrap only one app on me page. The issue is about rendering an ng2 component that render only one time on the page , but i expected more instances of it because it is in a `@foreach` in a Razor cshtml view.

Comment: So you create <app></app> tag of Angular2 in index.html ( or somewhere ) and inside that <app></app> you want to instantiate few other components? 

Than you should use Angualar2 template syntax:
<my-rating *nfFor="#rating of Items"></my-rating> 

I am not sure how you image to mix asp.net 5 view and angular2? Can you provide your code, Plunker or anything?

Comment: According to the [glossary](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/glossary.html#!#B) entry for bootstrap, "One can bootstrap multiple apps in the same index.html, each with its own top level root."